Atlassian Confluence REST API with 2FA two factor authentication
I am trying to establish a connection via the REST API of Confluence to read, create or change content. I have a valid token and admin rights for this.
The problem is that my company has secured this page with the Microsoft Authenticator, so I get a ‘401 - Unauthorised’ on every request.
Does anyone have any experience or an idea what steps are necessary to be able to use the REST API?
The background is that we have moved from another wiki to Confluence. All old wiki articles are to be exported and automatically imported into Confluence. This would theoretically be possible via the REST API.

I have found a way around the problem by using the JSESSION cookie that I received after logging into the browser and sending it in the Http request instead of the token.
But maybe someone still knows a way to do it the ‘right’ way and use the token.
